# Grub PXE boot - not looking for MAC/IP-based config

Tags: boot, grub2, uefi, pxe

I am PXE-booting an Ubuntu 22.04 installation. For the grub image, I am using the one [here](http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/jammy/main/uefi/grub2-amd64/current/grubnetx64.efi) .

According to [the docs](https://www.gnu.org/software/grub/manual/grub/html_node/Network.html):

```
GRUB will search for its configuration files in order using the following rules where the appended value corresponds to a value on the client machine.

‘(FWPATH)’/grub.cfg-‘(UUID OF MACHINE)’
‘(FWPATH)’/grub.cfg-‘(MAC ADDRESS OF NIC)’
‘(FWPATH)’/grub.cfg-‘(IPv4 OR IPv6 ADDRESS)’
‘(FWPATH)’/grub.cfg
```

However, there is no TFTP request for anything other than `grub.cfg`:

```
in.tftpd[7037]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename boot/tree/EFI/boot/bootx64.efi
in.tftpd[7038]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename boot/tree/EFI/boot/grubx64.efi
in.tftpd[7040]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename /grub/x86_64-efi/command.lst
in.tftpd[7041]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename /grub/x86_64-efi/fs.lst
in.tftpd[7042]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename /grub/x86_64-efi/crypto.lst
in.tftpd[7043]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename /grub/x86_64-efi/terminal.lst
in.tftpd[7044]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename /grub/grub.cfg
in.tftpd[7045]: RRQ from 10.128.128.13 filename /grub/fonts/unicode.pf2
```

My question is: how can I get grub to load different config files based on (for example) the MAC address?

[ Edited to add some details:

- yes, I did create a file called `grub.cfg-00-0a-11-22-33-44`, but it never gets downloaded/accessed
- I did read the section in the docs about `feature_net_search_cfg`, but I do not know how to figure out what the value of the setting is for my grub image
  ]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe the `grubnetx64.efi` image embedded config is changing the behavior.

```
if [ -e $prefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg ]; then
        source $prefix/x86_64-efi/grub.cfg
elif [ -e $prefix/grub.cfg-amd64 ]; then
        source $prefix/grub.cfg-default-amd64
else
        source $prefix/grub.cfg
fi
```

This config appears to be generated in [a build script](https://salsa.debian.org/grub-team/grub/-/blob/2d60a2ba1097b1bb8eb2f36f6df025b860ee6ba2/debian/build-efi-images#L73).  If you boot this image and open a grub command line then the config is visible with `cat (memdisk)/grub.cfg`.

**option 1**

You can use a different grub image.  I have used a [Debian grub image](https://deb.debian.org/debian/dists/bookworm/main/installer-amd64/current/images/netboot/debian-installer/amd64/bootnetx64.efi) and a [Fedora grub image](https://archives.fedoraproject.org/pub/archive/fedora/linux/releases/36/Server/x86_64/os/images/efiboot.img) before to launch the Ubuntu installer.  They both to appear to use the default behavior for `feature_net_search_cfg`.  If Secure Boot is enabled then only the Ubuntu image can be used.

**option 2**

You can make your own grub image with the `grub-mknetdir` command.

**option 3**

You can use the Ubuntu image as is and duplicate the desired feature using the grub configuration.  If you want to load a grub config based on the MAC address then `grub.cfg` contents could simply contain

```
source ${prefix}/grub.cfg-${net_default_mac}
```

Comment: Thank you for the detailed answer. After struggling with the grub image from the `cd-boot-images-amd64` package (which doesn't even bother to look up the config over the network), now I find out that  the Ubuntu `grubNETx64` image has `net_search` disabled. Some... very questionable decisions from the package maintainers :)

Once again, thank you!